# Attribute Error 'function' object has no attribute 'DataType'

Tags: python, gis, python-2.x, raster

I am thinking this is an easy fix and likely due to me being meh at python.

What I am trying to do is take this 4 banded [NAIP](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xeoY_LL3tVouSES6SlORjJsz_WFk9JA0/view?usp=sharing) and create a 432 false color image. Ultimately to create a script that will run through hundreds of these images to do so, but that is clearly far off.

I keep receiving an error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'DataType'` 
If I enter a DataType ex: `gdal.GDT_Byte` (which i don't fully understand) then later I get an error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'shape'` Which leads me to believe either there is something different between this raster and the one I used in a similar function for class OR I am fundamentally reading in the raster wrong.

Here is my full code:

```
import os
from osgeo import gdal

#change directory to data location
data_folder = r'my directory'
os.chdir(data_folder)

#open the .tif file and its bands, make sure they opened properly
ds = gdal.Open('example.tif') 
if ds is None: 
    raise IOError('Cound not open raster ya n00b')
band1 = ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray
if band1 is None:
    raise IOError('bandz 1 didnt make her dance')
band2 = ds.GetRasterBand(2).ReadAsArray
if band2 is None:
    raise IOError('bandz 2 didnt make her dance')
band3 = ds.GetRasterBand(3).ReadAsArray
if band3 is None:
    raise IOError('bandz 3 didnt make her dance')
band4 = ds.GetRasterBand(4).ReadAsArray
if band4 is None:
    raise IOError('bandz 4 didnt make her dance')

#Get the GeoTiff driver to create an output raster    
gtiff_driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')

#Get the data type name
data_type = band1.DataType
data_type = gdal.GetDataTypeName(data_type)

test_1 = gtiff_driver.Create('test_v1.tif', ds.RasterXSize, ds.RasterYSize, 3, gdal.GDT_Byte)
if test_1 is None:
    raise IOError('Could not create raster test_1')

test_1.SetProjection(ds.GetProjection())
test_1.SetGeoTransform(ds.GetGeoTransform())

t1_band1 = test_1.GetRasterBand(1)
t1_band1.WriteArray(band4)

t1_band2 = test_1.GetRasterBand(2)
t1_band2.WriteArray(band3)

t1_band3 = test_1.GetRasterBand(3)
t1_band3.WriteArray(band2)

del t1_band1, t1_band2, t1_band3, test_1, ds
```

I feel like I am just being dumb here but would really appreciate some help. Oh and I am still using Python 2, I know i need to switch soon. Thank you!

Comment: functions don't normally have attributes, so band1 is not what you think it is. As a wild guess, what happens if you do band1 = ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()  {note parentheses at the end}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think try

```
band1 = ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
```

with parentheses at the end.

The parentheses is python syntax to call the function and get the result.
Without the parentheses, you have made `band1` a synonym for the `ReadAsArray` function.
This can be helpful in other circumstances, you could do

```
 band1 = ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray    
 x = band1()
```

which calls `ReadAsArray`

but it is not what you wanted to do

Comment: Thank you so much! I need a big post it note on my computer that says DONT FORGET YOUR PARENTHESES.